# Correct way to walk a ParseTree ANTLR4

Tags: c++, antlr4, parse-tree

I am trying to implement a TSql parser using ANTLR4 with a C++ target.  I grabbed the grammar files [here](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/tsql).  The jar was used to make the corresponding source files (and changed all `NULL` to `null` in TSqlParser.cpp because of conflict).   I am following the [doc example](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/cpp-target.md) (and every other example on the net) which shows how to implement a single rule and listener which works fine.  The problem occurs when implementing multiple rules.

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h>
#include "TSqlParser.h"
#include "TSqlLexer.h"

#include "listener.h"


int main(int argc, const char* argv[])
{
    std::ifstream stream;
    stream.open(argv[1]);

    antlr4::ANTLRInputStream input(stream);
    TSqlLexer lexer(&input);
    antlr4::CommonTokenStream tokens(&lexer);
    TSqlParser parser(&tokens);

    TreeShapeListener listener;

    //antlr4::tree::ParseTree *select_tree = parser.select_statement();
    antlr4::tree::ParseTree *update_tree = parser.update_statement();

    //antlr4::tree::ParseTreeWalker::DEFAULT.walk(&listener, select_tree);
    antlr4::tree::ParseTreeWalker::DEFAULT.walk(&listener, update_tree);

    return 0;
}
```

listener.h:

```
#include <antlr4-runtime/antlr4-runtime.h>
#include "TSqlParserBaseListener.h"

class TreeShapeListener : public TSqlParserBaseListener
{
public:

    void enterSelect_statement(TSqlParser::Select_statementContext*) override;
    void enterUpdate_statement(TSqlParser::Update_statementContext*) override;
};
```

listener.cpp:

```
#include "listener.h"

void TreeShapeListener::enterSelect_statement(TSqlParser::Select_statementContext *ctx)
{
    std::cout << "Hello Select\n";
}

void TreeShapeListener::enterUpdate_statement(TSqlParser::Update_statementContext *ctx)
{
    std::cout << "Hello Update\n";
}
```

And here is a little test sql file:

```sql
SELECT TOP 1 NAME
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE SEQ = 6

UPDATE MYTABLE
SET NAME = 'Bob'
WHERE SEQ = 5
```

output:

```
line 1:0 mismatched input 'SELECT' expecting {'UPDATE', 'WITH'}
Hello Update
```

If I switch the SQL statements around, I will get just `Hello Update` so I think it is just gobbling up the entire input.  It all just seems like I need to hard code everything to get what I want.  My question is, how do I get the correct listeners to call themselves when I parse the file? I feel like I am missing something very key here to ANTLR.  I don't really need a full answer here, I just need someone to point me in the right direction.  It could be an API page... It has been a while since I wrote any Java, but it translates well enough that I can figure it out from there.

Comment: your entry point in the grammar is `tsql_file`. if you start at `update_statement`, the parser doesnt know about "SELECT".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you construct your tree by

```
antlr4::tree::ParseTree *update_tree = parser.update_statement();
```

you are only using a subset of your grammar, because your entry point is `tsql_file`.
The `update_statement` is the rule for the SQL keyword `UPDATE`, so it doesnt know what to do with `SELECT`.

Instead you should construct your tree by

```
antlr4::tree::ParseTree *tsql_file_tree = parser.tsql_file();
```